# Combine 2 object lists by index and retain key and value even if there are duplicates

Tags: java, list, merge, mapping

Have an object which has 2 lists.

Is there a way I could merge the 2 lists by index and still retain
key / values if there is a conflict between the 2 lists?

This is current object with 2 lists. The lists are not always of same length.

```
{
    "listA": [
        {
            "text": "index 0 list 1 text",
            "icon": "index 0 list 1 icon"
        },
        {
            "text": "index 1 list 1 text",
            "icon": "index 1 list 1 icon"
        }
    ],
    "listB": [
        {
            "text": "index 0 list 2 text"
        },
        {
            "title": "index 1 list 2 title",
            "text": "index 1 list 2 text",
            "icon": "index 1 list 2 icon"
        },
        {
            "title": "index 2 list 2 title 2",
            "text": "index 2 list 2 text 2",
            "icon": "index 2 list 2 icon 2"
        },
        {
            "header": "index 3 list 2 header 2",
            "icon": "index 3 list 2 icon 2"
        }
    ]
}
```

After merging looking to achieve following. (A new list)

```
{
    "listC": [
        {
            "text": "index 0 list 1 text",
            "icon": "index 0 list 1 icon",
            "text": "index 0 list 2 text"
        },
        {
            "text":  "index  1 list 1 text",
            "icon":  "index  1 list 1 icon",
            "title": "index  1 list 2 title",
            "text":  "index  1 list 2 text",
            "icon":  "index  1 list 2 icon"
        },
        {
            "title": "index  2 list 2 title 2",
            "text":  "index  2 list 2 text  2",
            "icon":  "index  2 list 2 icon  2"
        },
        {
            "header": "index 3 list 2 header 2",
            "icon":   "index 3 list 2 icon   2"
        }
    ]
}
```

Understand this is not feasible due to duplicate keys.
Thus one thought is to change the names for the keys in list 2 when merging.

Something like key `text` becomes `shortCopy` for list 1 and `longCopy` for list 2.

Thus resulting in:

```
{
    "shortCopy":  "index 0 list 1 text",
    "icon":  "index 0 list 1 icon",

    "longCopy": "index 0 list 2 text"
}
```

Is there an elegant way to achieve this via a stream?

Attempted following where I am creating a new object that holds different keys and adding that to a separate list.

Resulting in no conflicts.

Overall the question is, is there a more elegant approach to achieving this? Possibly with a Stream?

 As can see, this involved multiple loops and conditionals and the need to create a a new list and object.

Looking for a cleaner solution.

My attempt to achieve this.

```
MyObj myObj = // some REST call;
List<NewBenefit> newBenefits = new ArrayList<>();

List<InitialBenefit> list1 = myObj.getList1();
List<InitialBenefit> list2 = myObj.getList2();

List<Benefit> newBenefits = new ArrayList<>();

// just adding the list 1 key/values to new list first. 
for (InitialBenefit item : list1) {
    Benefit benefit = new Benefit();
    benefit.setIcon(item.getIcon());
    benefit.setShortCopy(item.getText());
    newBenefits.add(benefit);
}

for (int i = 0; i < list2.size(); i++) {
    // newBenefits list now exists with some objects. 
    // so check if add new object or update keys in existing object
    // within the list
    if (newBenefits.size() > i) {
        Benefit benefit = newBenefits.get(i);
        benefit.setIcon(list2.get(i).getIcon());
        benefit.setLongCopy(list2.get(i).getText());
    } else {
        Benefit benefit = new Benefit();
        benefit.setIcon(list2.get(i).getIcon());
        benefit.setLongCopy(list2.get(i).getText());
        newBenefits.add(benefit);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is that what your data really looks like?  Strings which say ""text": "index 0 list 1 text".  If not please show any lists or maps with the data is it exists before and after processing.  Show  your data as though you were entering it into Java code for processing.  Using `List.of()` or `Map.of().`etc.  In other words, show fully initialized data structures before and after processing.  You could put it in a [mre].  Also include any classes you created.